# What's the new hexagonal structure for in Boca Chica TX, SpaceX

Tags: identify-this-object, spacex-starship, launchpad, spacex-super-heavy

At Boca Chica Texas at the SpaceX launch facility there is a new structure being built. [RGV Aerial Photography](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYEDVMcsDKA) shows a concrete base with six pillars being built in a hexagonal shape. What is this structure intended for?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure is in the area designated by SpaceX as a launch pad for Starship Super Heavy.

There was a [public notice filed with the U.S. ARMY CORPS OF ENGINEERS GALVESTON TX](https://www.swg.usace.army.mil/Media/Public-Notices/Article/2524314/swg-2013-00381-space-exploration-technologies-inc-spacex-wetlands-cameron-count/)

The [project plans](https://www.swg.usace.army.mil/Portals/26/docs/regulatory/PN%20March/Plans_201300381.pdf?ver=hid3b2HjHCZZNucHf1LGzw%3d%3d) show that this structure is "ORBITAL PAD A LAUNCH MOUNT" with an integration tower adjacent.

[image: plot of orbital launch mount]

Thanks to ArsTechnica for alerting us to this information: [Article by ArsTechnica: SpaceX reveals the grand extent of its starport plans in South Texas](https://arstechnica.com/science/2021/03/spacex-reveals-the-grand-extent-of-its-starport-plans-in-south-texas/)